# Datastore use case

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

RDMS guy here. Let's say that I have two entities and will have to join them and filter the join. In RDMB SQL it would be something like:

```
select *
from entity1 e1, entity2 e2
where e1.id = e2.fk_id
and e1.this = 'that';
```

From what I can understand, with Datastore I have to do this in memory, on that one GAE instance which is running the query:

- load `entity1` from datastore with filter `this = 'that'`
- load everything from datastore for `entity2` (or multiple calls for each `entity1.id` after running distinct on them)
- join in memory

If the data set becomes large (more than RAM I have, especially as `entity2` grows and I serve simultaneous requests), the above query just cannot be done. Is this correct?

What is the usual way of dealing with this:

- just store the data de-normalised in `huge_entity` (this feels so wrong)?
- distribute the join/filter across GAE instances? (how is this done if yes?)
- use parent keys for this specific purpose?
- just keep adding more RAM :) ?
- ditch datastore for cloudsql?

Comment: Use a demormalised entity, if you don't use all of the data in the denormallised entity all of the time, then create children that hold the occasionally used data or fetch it from the original entities.  

Alternately create join entities. ie denormallised entities expressing the relationship and have just the properties from each that make the query perform and allows summary views.  

The specific choice has a lot more to do with what you do with the join once filtered.  ie remove unnecessary round trips to the datastore.